# play 2.6.x logging request body and process time

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using play server 2.6.x and trying to log the request body and the process time of every request.

The problem is that if I'm using Play `Filter` api I don't have access to request body, and if I'm using play `Action` api to wrap the action as `LoggingAction` I have access to the body but can't have the response time, so I had to use them both and create a unique id for each request and update log by request id.

It seems to me that there has to be much more elegant solution.

Comment: Perhaps asking in the forum will lead to more answers? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also found an answer to my question, it seems to me a little bit more easy so i will share it.

It involves creating your own `Action` to have the ability to parse the request body, and also log all headers.

```
case class LoggingAction @Inject(override val parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser){
  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], invoke: (Request[A] => Future[Result])): Future[Result] ={
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
    try {
      invoke(request).map(res => {
        val processTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis - startTime
        Logger.log(request,time)
        res
      })
    } catch {
      // Throw some error...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question - It wasn't trivial to find the answer - take a look at the play.test.Helpers class - you have methods that achieve that there.

Which one to use will depend if you have access to the Materializer or not and/or where/how you're doing the log. If it's a filter or an action.

In my case, I use it as an Action, and the code that matches my similar requirements is:
```

```
@Override
public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context context) {
    if(environment.isProd()) {
        //let's just not log anything
        delegate.call(context);
    }
    CompletionStage<Result> callResult = null;
    try {


    Http.RequestBody body = context.request().body();
    final String basicCallIdentifier = "Call: " + context.request().method() + ":"  + context.request().uri();
    String requestMessage = "Request - " + basicCallIdentifier;
    if(body != null) {
        requestMessage +=   " body: " + body.asText();
    }
        LOG.debug(requestMessage);
        callResult = delegate.call(context);
        return callResult.whenComplete((result, throwable) -> {
            String resultMessage = "Response - " + basicCallIdentifier + ":";
            if(result == null) {
                resultMessage += " Null result!";
                LOG.debug(resultMessage, throwable);
            } else {
                resultMessage += " Status: " +result.status();
                HttpEntity resultBody = result.body();
                if(resultBody != null
                        && resultBody.contentType().isPresent()
                        && resultBody.contentType().get().contains("json")) {
                    HttpEntity.Strict resultBodyStrict = (HttpEntity.Strict) resultBody;
                    ByteString byteString = resultBodyStrict.data();
                    resultMessage +=  " body: " + byteString.decodeString("UTF-8");

                }
                LOG.debug(resultMessage, throwable);

            }
        });



    } catch(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Caught exception on APILogAction", ex);
        if(callResult == null) {
            callResult = delegate.call(context);
        }
        return callResult;
    }
```

}

```